# Python Challenge # 2 = removing characters from a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code:

```
theory = """}#)$[]_+(^_@^][]_)*^*+_!{&$##]((](}}{[!$#_{&{){
*_{^}$#!+]{[^&++*#!]*)]%$!{#^&%(%^*}@^+__])_$@_^#[{{})}$*]#%]{}{][@^!@)_[}{())%)
())&#@*[#}+#^}#%!![#&*}^{^(({+#*[!{!}){(!*@!+@[_(*^+*]$]+@+*_##)&)^(@$^]e@][#&)(
%%{})+^$))[{))}&$(^+{&(#%*@&*(^&{}+!}_!^($}!(}_@@++$)(%}{!{_]%}$!){%^%%@^%&#([+[
_+%){{}(#_}&{&++!@_)(_+}%_#+]&^)+]_[@]+$!+{@}$^!&)#%#^&+$@[+&+{^{*[@]#!{_*[)(#[[
]*!*}}*_(+&%{&#$&+*_]#+#]!&*@}$%)!})@&)*}#(@}!^(]^@}]#&%)![^!$*)&_]^%{{}(!)_&{_{
+[_*+}]$_[#@_^]*^*#@{&%})*{&**}}}!_!+{&^)__)@_#$#%{+)^!{}^@[$+^}&(%%)&!+^_^#}^({
*%]&@{]++}@$$)}#]{)!+@[^)!#[%@^!!"""

#theory = open("temp.txt")

key = "#@!$%+{}[]_-&*()*^@/"
new2 =""

print()
for letter in theory:
    if letter not in key:
        new2 += letter

print(new2)
```

This is a test piece of code to solve the python challenge #2: http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html

The only trouble is, the code I wrote seems to leaves lots of whitespace but I'm not sure why.

Any ideas on how to remove the unnecessary white? In other words I want the code to return "e" not "     e    ".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The challenge is to find a rare character. You could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for that:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(theory)
print(c.most_common()[-1])
```

#### Output

```
('e', 1)
```

The unnecessary whitespace could be removed using [`.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
new2.strip()
```

Adding `'\n'` to the `key` works too.

Answer (score 2):

The best would be to use regular expression library, like so

```
import re
characters = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]", sourcetext)
print ("".join(characters))
```

In a resulting string you will have ONLY an alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the distribution of characters (using `collections.Counter`), you get:

- 6000+ each of `)@(]#_%[}!+$&{*^` (which you are correctly excluding from the output)
- 1220 newlines (which you are **not** excluding from the output)
- 1 each of — no, I'm not going to give away the answer

Just add `\n` to your `key` variable to exclude the unwanted newlines.  This will leave you with just the rare (i.e., 1 occurrence only) characters you need.

P.S., it's highly inefficient to concatenate strings in a loop.  Instead of:

```
new2 =""

for letter in theory:
    if letter not in key:
        new2 += letter
```

write:

```
new2 = ''.join(letter for letter in theory if letter not in key)
```

Comment: It's no longer inefficient to build the string with +=. If new2 is the only reference to the string, Python extends it in place without copying (if there is enough space allocated at the end). See stringobject.c and search for _PyString_Resize

Answer (score 1):

The `theory` string contains several newlines. They get printed by your code. You can either get rid of the newline, like this:

```
theory = "}#)$[]_+(^_@^][]_)*^*+_!{&$##]((](}}{[!$#_{&{){" \
"*_{^}$#!+]{[^&++*#!]*)]%$!{#^&%(%^*}@^+__])_$@_^#[{{})}$*]#%]{}{][@^!@)_[}{())%)" \
"())&#@*[#}+#^}#%!![#&*}^{^(({+#*[!{!}){(!*@!+@[_(*^+*]$]+@+*_##)&)^(@$^]e@][#&)(" \
"%%{})+^$))[{))}&$(^+{&(#%*@&*(^&{}+!}_!^($}!(}_@@++$)(%}{!{_]%}$!){%^%%@^%&#([+[" \
"_+%){{}(#_}&{&++!@_)(_+}%_#+]&^)+]_[@]+$!+{@}$^!&)#%#^&+$@[+&+{^{*[@]#!{_*[)(#[[" \
"]*!*}}*_(+&%{&#$&+*_]#+#]!&*@}$%)!})@&)*}#(@}!^(]^@}]#&%)![^!$*)&_]^%{{}(!)_&{_{" \
"+[_*+}]$_[#@_^]*^*#@{&%})*{&**}}}!_!+{&^)__)@_#$#%{+)^!{}^@[$+^}&(%%)&!+^_^#}^({" \
"*%]&@{]++}@$$)}#]{)!+@[^)!#[%@^!!"
```

or your can filter them out, like this:

```
key = "#@!$%+{}[]_-&*()*^@/\n"
```

Both work fine (yes, I tested).

Answer (score 0):

a simpler way to output the answer is to:

```
print ''.join([ c for c in theory if c not in key])
```

and in your case you might want to add the newline character to key to also filter it out:

```
key += "\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd better work in reverse, something like this:

```
out = []                                                                                                       
for i in theory:                                                                                                 
  a = ord(i)                                                                                                   
  if (a > 96 and a < 122) or (a > 65 and a < 90):                                                              
    out.append(chr(a))                                                                                         

print ''.join(out)
```

Or better, use a regexp.